# Laravel Custom attributes affecting data insertion to db

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, custom-attributes

I have created custom attributes so that I can directly access them in my blade file and it works well, but during my testing in my db, it is the one that gives the `QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'` error. Here's what I've done in inserting the custom attributes in my model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'room_name',
    'room_code',
];

protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];

protected $attributes = ['room_total_booking', 'room_complete_booking'];

public function getRoomTotalBookingAttribute($id){
    return \App\Models\Guest\BookingDetail::where('room_list_id', $id)->count();
}

public function getRoomCompleteBookingAttribute($id){
    return \App\Models\Guest\BookingDetail::where('room_list_id', $id)->whereReservationStatus(1)->count();
}
```

But when I comment out the attributes, it works well. Here is the full error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `room_lists` (`0`, `1`, `room_name`, `room_code`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (room_total_booking, room_complete_booking, Test2, Test101, 2019-11-05 11:00:16, 2019-11-05 11:00:16))

**SAVING TO DB**

```
    $room = [];
    $room['room_name'] = $data['room_name'];
    $room['room_code'] = $data['room_code'];

    $rtn = $this->roomList->create($room);
```

If you can see it, my declared custom attributes are in the `value` fields. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: share where you tried inserting and update the question

Comment: @spartyboy please see update.

Comment: Try to do this:
`$rtn = $this->roomList->create([
'room_name' => $data['room_name'],
'room_code' => $data['room_code']
]);`

Comment: @MED Unfortunately, it's still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Got it. I used `append` instead of `attributes`

```
protected $append = ['room_total_booking', 'room_complete_booking'];
```

And it now solve my problem.